# How do I change the listen port for Nextcloud in Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, nextcloud, port-443

I recently installed Nextcloud via Docker using the default commands in various tutorials.  After doing so, I realized that I need Nextcloud to listen on different ports than 443 and 80 via Docker.  How do I change this without rebuilding my install completely?  I tried updating a .json file that was suggested, but it reverted back every time I started the container again (I stopped it before editing, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about published ports of your container, you need to delete and recreate it to change the ports.

If you built it properly, mounting a volume or external directory for the data, this is as trivial as re-running the modified original command.